# typeError: Cannot read property 'tigerStart' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, typescript

- I am new to typescript and angular js.
- I tried to include another component code into my code.
- which is baby.js code into my code
- but I am getting an error. TypeError: Cannot read property 'tigerStart' of undefined
- can you guys tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code below

```or-tag-here
TypeError: Cannot read property 'tigerStart' of undefined
    at init.open (pen-pencil.ts:1270)
    at init.trigger (kendo.all.min.js:25)
    at init.open (kendo.all.min.js:45)
    at Penguin.openPopup (pen-pencil.ts:1286)
    at penguin.pencilClicked (headset.ts:689)
    at _View_penguin4._handle_click_45_0 (penguin.ngfactory.js:4087)
    at eval (core.umd.js:9698)
    at eval (platform-browser.umd.js:1877)
    at eval (platform-browser.umd.js:1990)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:203)
```

**including tigerStart method into whole js code**

@ViewChild(sports) public sky: sports;

```or-tag-here
that.window = $("#PenguinPopup");
that.window.kendoWindow({
  width: "60%",
  title: false,
  visible: false,
  resizable: false,
  actions: [],
  draggable: false,
  modal: true,
  open: function() {
    $("html, body").css("overflow", "hidden");
    that.isVisible = true;
    $('.kPopUpTitle').html(values.title);
    this.sky.tigerStart();
```

**including fish component into my html**

```or-tag-here
<div class="clearFloat"></div>
<ul class="kendu-custom-contextmenu" id="context-menuFinancialSearch">
  <li class="kPopUpBtnTriple">View Details</li>
  <li class="kPopUpBtnTriple">Manage Documents</li>
</ul>

<financeLeftSlider (savedSearchData)='getSaveEvent($event)'></financeLeftSlider>

<Fish></Fish>
<Penguin (documentCount)='getDocumentEvent($event)'></Penguin>
<sports></sports>

<div class="searchNameRequiredPopup">
  <div class="pipepobUpBox pipeWindow kPopupConfirmationBox">
    <div class="row pipePopUpGridCollection pipePopUpContent lineHeightInputs">
      <div class="pipeContent">Please enter the search name.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearFloat"></div>
    <div class="row pipePopUpFooter textAligncenterImp">
      <!-- <button class="commonBtn" type="button" id ="deleteDocumentYes">Yes</button> -->
      <button class="clearBtn" type="button" id="searchNameRequiredBtn">Ok</button>
    </div>
    <div class="clearFloat"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

baby.html

```or-tag-here
<div id="baby"></div>
<div id="baby1"></div>
```

baby.js

```or-tag-here
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sports',
  templateUrl: 'sports.html'
})

export class Star {

  tigerStart(): void {
    kendo.ui.sky($("#baby"), true);
  }
  tigerEnd(): void {
    kendo.ui.sky($("#baby"), false);

  }

  tigerStart1(): void {
    kendo.ui.sky($("#baby1"), true);
  }
  tigerEnd1(): void {
    kendo.ui.sky($("#baby1"), false);
  }

}
```

- when I print this I didn't see sky, so I read the medium form and tried with fat arrow and bind but still I am not able to achived it.
- in the view child I am using sports
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- so that for future it will be helpful

**https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/es5-functions-vs-es6-fat-arrow-functions-864033baa1a**

```or-tag-here
@ViewChild(sports) public sky: sports;
**- tried with fat arrow**
open: () => {

**- tried with bind**
        this.sky.tigerStart().bind(this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Looking like an object having property key **`tigerStart`** is undefined.

**You can debug like this :**

- First, you should make sure that an object having property key **`tigerStart`** actually returns an object and not "undefined".

**Example :** Suppose `tiger` is an object having property with key `tigerStart`.

```
{
  "tiger": {
    "tigerStart": true
  }
}

if (typeof tiger != 'undefined') {
  /* Your code comes here */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In this line:

```
this.sky.tigerStart();
```

You're expecting `this.sky` to be set to something, but it's not. That's because the `this` is not what you think it is; you are not in the *scope* you think you are in. Add a `console.dir(this)` right before this line, refresh the page, and check the browser console if you want to see what your `this` is. Then figure out some other way to resolve the object you really need there.

[Mozilla Developer Network reference article for "this"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Try the following:

```
// *** Assign this to a variable (self)
var self = this;

that.window = $("#PenguinPopup");
that.window.kendoWindow({
  width: "60%",
  title: false,
  visible: false,
  resizable: false,
  actions: [],
  draggable: false,
  modal: true,
  open: function() {
    $("html, body").css("overflow", "hidden");
    that.isVisible = true;
    $('.kPopUpTitle').html(values.title);

// *** use the self variable instead of this
    self.sky.tigerStart();
```

The article you mention in your comment is correct, but if you don't really understand what's is happening in the code, it will only confuse you more if you try to do what it's suggesting. You may want to study more about how variable scope works in Javascript. It's a bit confusing in the beginning, but understanding will help you get better at Javascript. I still have problems with it myself, but the way I show here, is fairly easy to understand. Just remember when you declare a variable and you declare functions at the same level (or inside those functions), you can access that variable from inside those functions (unless you create new variables with the same names inside those functions).

Comment: thanks for your reply.  - when I print this I didn't see sky, so I read the medium form and tried with fat arrow and bind but still I am not able to achived it.
  - in the view child I am using sports
  -  can you tell me how to fix it.
  - so that for future it will be helpful

Comment: https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/es5-functions-vs-es6-fat-arrow-functions-864033baa1a

  @ViewChild(sports) public sky: sports;



open: () => {

        this.sky.tigerStart().bind(this);

Comment: I read the article you referenced. Interesting. I didn't know the ES6 "fat arrow" kept the 'this' scope in that way. But anyway, the changes you made have made a mess of things. You call bind but at that line, it's already too late to do that, because you are already inside the function. You have not really given enough information for me to simply fix your problem. I can only guess. I will try to update my answer with something you can try to see if it works for you.

Comment: Hey why you use self... without using self can't I achieve it :(

Comment: hey updated whole code in fiddle...can you help me https://gist.github.com/texirv0203/d3ac52678f3f977258f4ac293c104bcf

Comment: It's difficult to read the code. There's a lot. How do you know that `sky` was set to a valid value? Where is the code that does that? (BTW, you are trying to call this.sky.tigerStart() in two different places. Line 507 and line 1150.)

Comment: @ultrmoka thanks for your reply...hey even after commenting at line 507 I am seeing the error...if loading time is very low I need to see a circle loading...thats the reason I used at two places...can you help me

Comment: You didn't answer my questions about `sky`. Where is the code that sets the value of `sky`?

Comment: That is coming from baby.js...i think baby.js is a child component

Comment: Hey I read Mozilla article but still confused...can you tell after using var self = this; it's working but for some cases in my code without using self variable they are directly using this and it's working

Answer (score 2):

The `this` keyword refers to the current context. In this case, it is the context of the object you are calling `open()` with.

```
that.window = $("#PenguinPopup");
that.window.kendoWindow({
  width: "60%",
  title: false,
  visible: false,
  resizable: false,
  actions: [],
  draggable: false,
  modal: true,
  open: function() {
    $("html, body").css("overflow", "hidden");
    that.isVisible = true;
    $('.kPopUpTitle').html(values.title);
    this.sky.tigerStart();
```

As you can see the current context is the Object fed into `that.window.kendoWindow()`. For your given code to work, it would need to look something like this:

```
that.window = $("#PenguinPopup");
that.window.kendoWindow({
  width: "60%",
  title: false,
  visible: false,
  resizable: false,
  actions: [],
  draggable: false,
  modal: true,
  sky: {
     tigerStart: function () {
        // Do something here...
     }
  },
  open: function() {
    $("html, body").css("overflow", "hidden");
    that.isVisible = true;
    $('.kPopUpTitle').html(values.title);
    this.sky.tigerStart();
```

Now `this.sky` exists and you can access the given function.

Comment: hey how will you represent with the arrow function...is it same...since in that medium article they said its different for arrow functions :(

Comment: `open()` is not using an es6 arrow function. An arrow function handles scope differently. Take a look at this article: https://toddmotto.com/es6-arrow-functions-syntaxes-and-lexical-scoping/#functionality-lexical-scoping-this

Comment: In its current state, `this.sky.tigerStart()` should reference the added object and function. Try it.

Comment: Hey can you tell me in case if open uses arrow function... how to achieve it

Comment: `open: function() {}` would be `open: () => {}`. I don't think that this will fix your issue though.

Comment: Are you aware of what you are attempting to fix, or is something randomly braking?

Comment: Also, I am not suggesting that you use an arrow function. Just explaining what it is and does. Take a look at my actual answer. If you incorporate that into your code, it will not break.

Answer (score 1):

sky might be defined, but you are not assigning it a value before you are accessing it. Where are you assigning a value sky?

It is unclear if you mean that you are using Angular or if you mean you are using AngularJS. In the tags you have used the Angular tag. In the description you have mentioned AngularJS. These are two different things. You are also using $ which I assume is jquery. I suggest avoiding mixing jQuery with Angular or AngularJS. It will make your learning process much simpler.